# Не работает функция: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: javascript, функции

Вот код который должен делать арифметическое дейстивие: умножать, делить и т.д. (в зависимости от аргумента):

```
let action = (a, b, operator) => a operator b
action(8, 2, "/") // Должно быть 4 но не выводит
```

Но мне выдает ошибку

> "Unexpected token, expected ";" (1:35)".

Что интересно, этот код работает:

```
let action2 = (a, b) => a / b 
action2(8, 2) // => Выводит 4, как и должно быть
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти и исправить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно "заставить" JS вычислить строку с оператором — от того, что вы просто поставите в ряд числа и строчку с оператором, магическим образом выражение не вычислится. Попробуйте так:

```js
let action = (a, b, operator) => eval(`${a} ${operator} ${b}`);

console.log(action(8, 2, "/"));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

`let action = (a, b, operator) => a operator b`

В коде нельзя разбросать случайные переменные через пробелы. А если расставить требуемые точки-запятые,

`let action = (a, b, operator) => a; operator; b;`

↓

```
let action = (a, b, operator) => a;
operator;
b;
```

Оно уже по очевидной причине не будет работать как ожидалось.

---

```js
console.log( action(3, "+", 2) );
console.log( action(3, "-", 2) );
console.log( action(3, "*", 2) );
console.log( action(3, "/", 2) );
console.log( action(3, "^", 2) );

function action (a, oper, b) {
  
  switch (oper) {
    case "+": return a + b;
    case "-": return a - b;
    case "*": return a * b;
    case "/": return a / b;
    case "^": return a ** b;
    
    default: throw new Error("Unknown operator: " + oper);
  }
  
}
```